# Change to short Monthname in datetime2 (german)

Tags: packages, datetime2

I use `\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime2}` and try to create a date which uses the short form of the `Monthname`.

When I type `\DTMdate{2016-12-4}` I get as result `4. Dezember 2016`.
But I want the short `Monthname` `4. Dez. 2016`

I searched the documentation, tried changing the style, searched this forum and the Web but can't find any solution.
I think one of the problems is, the `ngerman` package of `datetime2` doesn't support short `Monthname`s?

but I also tried creating them with

```
\newcommand*{\DTMgermanshortMonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  \or
  Jän.%
  \or
  Feb.%
  \or
  März%
  \or
  Apr.%
  \or
  Mai%
  \or
  Juni%
  \or
  Juli%
  \or
  Aug.%
  \or
  Sep.%
  \or
  Okt.%
  \or
  Nov.%
  \or
  Dez.%
  \fi
}
```

When I tried this I always got error messages and I'm still not sure how to tell `datetime2` to change the style to use the `shortMonthname`.

I can't believe I am trying for 3h to change this -,-

Thanks for your Help!

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\DTMdate{2016-12-4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think it is just a matter of defining the short names. You'd have to rewrite the style commands to use them, preferably conditionally, in the way the English module does. However, good luck with that. My attempts to do this have all been abject failures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I define `\DTMshortdate{}`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime2}
\let\svDTMgermanmonthname\DTMgermanmonthname
\newcommand\DTMshortdate[1]{%
  \def\DTMgermanmonthname##1{%
    \ifcase##1%
    \or Jän.\or Feb.\or März\or Apr.\or Mai\or Juni% 
    \or Juli\or Aug.\or Sep.\or Okt.\or Nov.\or Dez.\fi
  }%
  \DTMdate{#1}%
  \let\DTMgermanmonthname\svDTMgermanmonthname%
}
\begin{document}
\DTMshortdate{2016-12-4}

\DTMdate{2016-12-4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need the long date form and wish to define `\DTMdate` to always use the short date, then that is simpler still

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime2}
  \def\DTMgermanmonthname#1{%
    \ifcase#1%
    \or Jän.\or Feb.\or März\or Apr.\or Mai\or Juni% 
    \or Juli\or Aug.\or Sep.\or Okt.\or Nov.\or Dez.\fi
  }%
\begin{document}
\DTMdate{2016-12-4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works fine :)
I'm still surprised datetime2 doesn't support this feature without extra Code, but your solution works perfectly fine for me.